# i am continuously being wrong with this data overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display the text under the images. I am able to see the Images and text, but My text is overflowing. I want to display it on each text under each image. Below is my code.

What should I do to solve this situation.

[image: img]

```
Widget firstStyleRow(String ImgPath1, String ImgPath2, String avatarImg) {
    return Container(
      height: 250.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 250.0,
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0) / 2,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 125.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(ImgPath1),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'i like the wy to show more item',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 30.0,
                      width: 30.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/chris.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'mon hll',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '10:28 pm',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 350,
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0) / 2,
            child: Container(
              height: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/letter.jpeg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            child: Text(
              'i hvxxxx',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include that full row widget tree?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.add your inside row widget wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible`, just change my images with your images

```
Container(
      height: 250.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 250.0,
              width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0) / 2,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 125.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'i like the wy to show more item',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 30.0,
                            width: 30.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'mon hll',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '10:28 pm',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 350,
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0) / 2,
            child: Container(
              height: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
              child: Text(
                'i hvxxxx',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 50,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]